# How to set timer inside while

Tags: c#

I have a `while` loop. I want to step out of this while in 2 cases:

1. I found what I need
2. it took me more than 10 secs to find it

I know that I can set date startTime before while and check inside when `NowTime -startTime > 10000`, like so:

```
         DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
            while (Find == false)
            {
                //code

                if()Find=true;
                 DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
                if(end-start>10)Find=true;
            }
```

But I'm looking for a more elegant decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if that is what you are looking for, but I would go with Stopwatch class from System.Diagnostics namespace:

```
static class Program
{
    private static readonly Random Rnd = new Random((int)DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        stopwatch.Start();
        bool isFound;
        while (true)
        {
            isFound = Find();

            if (isFound || stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds >= 10)
                break;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Is found: {0}, Spent time: {1} sec(s)", isFound, stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static bool Find()
    {
        return Rnd.Next(1000) >= 999;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code sample won't work, because if the search logic (the "// code"  part in your example) takes more than 10 secs to execute, you won't reach your test until it is finished.

What you should do is execute your operation in a separate thread, and use a timeout on this thread.

For example:

```
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        var findThread = new Thread(Find);
        findThread.Start();

        if (!findThread.Join(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)))
        {
            findThread.Abort();
            Debug.WriteLine("Find timeout occured");
            // Handle find timeout
        }
    }

    private static void Find()
    {
        //Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));

        Debug.WriteLine("Find succeeded");
    }
```

Uncomment the `Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))` line (and comment the other `Thread.Sleep`) to verify that it's working as expected when the find method executes in less than 10 seconds.

Comment: It's only examlpe i know it(the "// code" part) will take less then 0.5 sec but i dont wont it to run more than 10 sec

Answer (score 0):

Use [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class. It has [ElapsedMilliseconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsedmilliseconds.aspx) property, which you could check on every iteration of your loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite common situation, so I have provided this procedure directly from my code:

```
public delegate Boolean WaitTestDelegate();
public static Boolean WaitUntil(WaitTestDelegate testDelegate,
    Int32 milliseconds = 10000, Int32 pariodDuration = 10)
{
    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now; Double timeSpan = 0;
    while (!testDelegate() &&
        (timeSpan = (DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalMilliseconds) < milliseconds)
        Thread.Sleep(pariodDuration);
    return timeSpan < milliseconds;
}
```

Procedure will return `true` if loop has finished before time elapsed.

`milliseconds` is total time to wait.

`periodDuration` is the time period to wait before `testDelegate` is invoked periodically.

`testDelegate` is method where you can put your test code, for example:

```
() => { return Find; }
```

Finally, call this procedure from your code:

`WaitUntil(() => { return Find; });` or `WaitUntil(() => Find);`

If you need asynchronous wait, create thread and run your code into thread, but that's different story.